# logistic regression and coefficient

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am trying to determine if the beta estimated from the logistic regression (from sklearn library) is matched or closed to the beta that I used to create the result with the use of logistic function (1/(1 + exp(-(b*x))). Here is the code I used

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

a = np.random.random_sample(100) * 12 - 6
a = np.sort(a)
t = 1/(1 + np.exp(-1 * (6 * (a)))) # I create a beta of 6
for i in range(len(t)):
    if t[i] >= 0.5:
        t[i] = 1
    else:
        t[i] = 0
a = np.array([a]).T
ones = np.array([[1]*len(a)]).T
a = np.concatenate((ones, a), axis=1)
lg = LogisticRegression()
lg.fit(a, t)
print(lg.coef_) # the estimated beta from the logistic regression model is [[ 0.24941991  2.41880381]]
```

The beta I preset is 6, however, the beta from logistic regression is 2.39662781. Even though I did an approximation for only getting 1 and 0, the two beta are still too different. Moreover, when I increase the beta that I preset, the estimated beta from the model sometimes increase but sometimes decreases, for example, if I preset the beta to be 7, then the beta estimated from the model is 2.15344631.

Can anyone explain to me what is going on? or How can a estimated beta that is closed to the one I created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logistic regression is a classifier, not a regressor. You remove information about the slope of the actual dividing line between positive and negative examples when you collapse the real values to 0s and 1s with the logistic function.

The value for beta determines the steepness of the line that separates 0s from 1s. To get a higher value for beta you need a smaller gap between the adjacent 0 and 1 values. For example if you replace `a = np.random.random_sample(100) * 12 - 6` with `a = np.linspace(-6, 6, 99)` you will get beta of around `2.4`. If you use `a = np.linspace(-6, 6, 999)` beta will be around `5.2`. But you should not expect to recover the original value because the loss function is cross-entropy on the 0s and 1s, not mean squared error on the original linear values, so there is no reward to the optimizer to recover the original slope, only to classify things correctly.